# Where can I find information about metametalogic

Tags: logic, foundations

I have been looking for information about metametalogic (theory about metalogic) but  I found basically nothing.
I would be grateful if anybody could refer me to a book or a publication. thanks.

Comment: What are you meaning with "metametalogic (theory about metalogic)" ? Metalogic (or metamathematics) is the study (mainly with mathematical methods) of mathematical logic and formalized mathematica theories. Metalogic is model theory and proof theory; if you want to "formalize" it, you need set theory.

Comment: " if you want to "formalize" it, you need set theory." Has anybody tried yet? Besides I  am a little bit confused, I thought set theory was just metalogic.

Comment: Again, what are you meaning with "metametalogic" ?? Metalogic is - for me - the study of properties of formalized systems: for example, the study of relation and notion like : *satisfiability*, *truth*, etc. To define in a "formal" way satisfiability, you have to "speak of" string of symbols, expressions, sequences. In order to do this, you have to use set theory.

Comment: You can see Helena Rasiowa & Roman Sikorski, *The Mathematics of Metamathematics* (1963) and Victor Marek, *Introduction to Mathematics of Satisfiability* (2009) for some examples.

Comment: Ok thanks, by metametalogic I mean a theory about metalogic, in other words a collection of axioms and propositions about meta logic.

Comment: Metamathematics, being a branch of mathematics, can be formalised in usual mathematical formal systems for arithmetic and set theory. Most discussions of, e.g. Gödel's Theorems will give some details about how to code up things like sentences as numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Metalogic, in a common understanding of that somewhat variously used term,  is mathematics applied to theories of interest to logicians (so the logician's theories are themselves treated as formal, mathematical objects).

Now most metalogic is done as informal maths. What's the informal toolkit we need to talk about theories-as-mathematical-objects? Stuff about formal strings (equivalent to arithmetic), the theory of computability, stuff about ordinals (for talking about proof theory), stuff about sets more generally (for when we are dealing with model theory), and such like. So a  metatheory for informal metalogic will be a theory about such theories of arithmetic, computation, ordinals, sets and stuff now treated as mathematical objects. But those are *already* the theories of interest to logicians one level down, so to speak, i.e. are already the topic of metalogic.

So you *could* say that metametalogic just is  metalogic again!

Which I guess is why you don't find people talking too much about metametalogic, as if there is a separate discipline waiting to be explored.

Comment: What about infinite chain of languages that was indicated by Alfred Tarski to cope with Liar's Paradox. I suspect question was about this infinite chain. That if math is object language and metalogic is meta language for math then there must be some next language that describe metalogic and so on.

Comment: That's confusing two "meta"s! Standard treatments of formal theories truth of truth (one department of metalogic, if you like) of course consider, inter alia, those theories which involve infinite hierarchies of languages. That doesn't involve having an infinite hierarchy of theories -- it's one (metalogical) theory about formal truth-predicates and their interactions with languages.

Comment: Ok  let's make a step backward and let's consider metalogic. For instance the Godel incompleteness Theorem is a result from metalogic.  What axioms  is this result  built on?

Comment: The incompleteness theorem was originally -- and in standard presentations still is -- a theorem of informal mathematics about what can be proved in formal theories with certain properties (it just uses known bits of mathematics as background). Proof analysis shows that a weak theory of arithmetic suffices to prove the result.

Comment: Ok thanks, I am afraid I still do not fully understand how a metalogic result can be based on the axioms of a logic system like arithmetic. Maybe you could tell me the book or the article where I can read about it. thanks again.

Comment: @user115415 - you can see an "easy" one: Richard Kaye, [The Mathematics of Logic: A Guide to Completeness Theorems and their Applications](http://www.amazon.com/The-Mathematics-Logic-Completeness-Applications/dp/052170877X/ref=tmm_pap_title_0?ie=UTF8&qid=1398788451&sr=1-1) (2007) and a "difficult" one: Yuri Manin, [A Course in Mathematical Logic for Mathematicians](http://www.amazon.com/Course-Mathematical-Mathematicians-Graduate-Mathematics/dp/1461424798/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1398788413&sr=1-2&keywords=Yuri+Manin+A+Course+in+Mathematical+Logic+for+Mathematicians) (2010).